# Angular write data lines dynamically to a table

Tags: html, angular, jsonplaceholder

In my project I getting the data from [JSONPlaceholder - Users](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)
I'm new in Angular, so if you find something stupid in the way I get the data please warn me.

```js
dataFromServer;
constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  this.dummyPromise.then(
    response => {
      console.log("response from dummy promise:", response);
      this.dataFromServer = response;
    },
    error => {
      console.log("Error happened with dummy promise:", error)
    }
  )
}

dummyPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.dataFromServer = data;
  });
  //resolve(returnData);
});
```

Problem is, in my HTML file, I write the data into a table like this:

```html
<tr *ngIf="dataFromServer">
  <td>{{dataFromServer[0].id}}</td>
  <td>{{dataFromServer[0].name}}</td>
  <td>{{dataFromServer[0].username}}</td>
  <td>{{dataFromServer[0].email}}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="dataFromServer">
  <td>{{dataFromServer[1].id}}</td>
  <td>{{dataFromServer[1].name}}</td>
  <td>{{dataFromServer[1].username}}</td>
  <td>{{dataFromServer[1].email}}</td>
</tr>
```

... for all the 10 people. I want to do it dynamically, as many lines as many people's data I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should try to use *ngFor instead of *ngIf. I will give you an example.

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of dataFromServer">
 <td>{{data.id}}</td>
<td>{{data.name}}</td> 
<td>{{data.username}}</td>
<td>{{data.email}}</td> 
</tr>
```

So, it will repeat for every object in your dataFromServer

Answer (score 0):

use `ngFor` to iterate on an array of data:

```
<table *ngIf="dataFromServer">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of dataFromServer">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

the `ngIf` condition on the `table` will prevent console errors/rendering issues if `dataFromServer` is null/undefined before receiving from your API

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngFor` to do it. It's pratically a for in the html. As an example we assume that we have a component like this :

```
private users: User[] = [];

ngOnInit(){
   this.service.getUser()
   .subscribe(userList => {
      this.users = userList;
   });
}
```

The User class :

```
export class User {
   public id: number;
   public name: string;
}
```

You can use the *ngFor in your html like this way :

```
<span *ngFor="let user of users">
UserID: {{user.id}} - User Name: {{user.name}}
</span>
```

So basically, related to your code, **just put in an object of User the json data you get from the http call**, then modify the html like this way :

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
  <td>{{user.id}}</td>
  <td>{{user.name}}</td>
  .....
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your html code as bellow

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of dataFromServer">
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.name}}</td> 
    <td>{{row.username}}</td>
    <td>{{row.email}}</td>
</tr>
```